# how do I make a 'csgocrash' style chart

Tags: javascript, plotly

I want to make a similar chart like on the picture below, that is drawing a line to a point which increases over time. numbers on the bottom are seconds (how many passed). is there any js library that would do that? I've tried with `chart.js` but I wasn't able to achieve what I wanted.

[image: what im trying to achieve]

here's what I tried with `plotly.js`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:400px;height:400px" id="myDiv"></div>
    <script>
        var numberX = 1;
        var numberY = 1;

        var data = [
        {
            x: [1, numberX],
            y: [2, numberY],
            type: 'scatter'
        }
        ];

        Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

        setInterval(function(){
            numberX++;
            numberY++;

            var data = [
            {
                x: [1, numberX],
                y: [2, numberY],
                type: 'scatter'
            }
            ];

            Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
        }, 1000);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

results are... not impressive:

[image: not impressive]

Comment: Questions asking us for libraries are off-topic for SO.   If you rewrite your question with the code you've tried, we can try helping you get it to work, though.

Comment: I added my code I tried so far, sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

heres some code that i wrote, had some free time and this seemed like a nice programming challenge. Couldnt get it exactly right, you are gonna have to improve it and play with the values but this is the basic idea:

```js
var mult = 0;
var ruler;
var inc;
var time=0;
var multt = 0.01;
var done = false;
var randomFac ;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 300);
  frameRate(15);
  ruler = new Ruler();
  inc = new Line();
  setInterval(myTimer, 50);
}

function draw() {
  background(30);

  stroke(150);
  strokeWeight(1);
  line(20, 20, 20, height - 20);
  line(20, height - 20, width - 20, height - 20);

  noStroke();
  fill(150);
  textSize(120);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text(mult.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0] + "x", width / 2, height / 2 + 20);

  if (mult > randomFac){
    console.log("stop");
    done = true;
  }

  if (!done){
  mult += multt;}

  if (!done){
  ruler.show();
  inc.show();
  }
}

function Ruler() {
  this.spc = 150;
  this.b = ((height - 20) / this.spc) / 2;

  this.show = function() {
    for (var a = 0; a < (width - 20) / this.spc; a++) {
      textAlign(CENTER);
      textSize(10);
      noStroke();
      fill(150);
      text(a, a * this.spc + 20, height - 8);
    }
    for (var a = 0; a < (height - 20) / this.spc; a++) {
      textAlign(CENTER);
      textSize(8);
      noStroke();
      fill(150);
      text(this.b.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0] + "x", 10, a * this.spc + 10);
      this.b -= 0.5;
    }
    this.b = ((height - 20) / this.spc) / 2;
  }
}

function Line() {

  this.show = function() {
    stroke(155);
    strokeWeight(2);
    beginShape();
    vertex(21, height - 20);
    if (height - 20 - (mult * (ruler.spc * 2)) + 20 < 280) {
      vertex(0 + 20 + (time * (ruler.spc )) - 20, height - 20 - (mult * (ruler.spc * 2)) + 20);
    }
    endShape();

    if (0 + 20 + (time * (ruler.spc )) - 20 >= 480 ||  height - 20 - (mult * (ruler.spc * 2)) + 20 <= 20){
      ruler.spc -= 1;
    }
  }
}

function myTimer () {
  time += 0.05;
  multt += 0.00005;
}
```

i hope this helps you in some way, have a nice day.

You can see the code working here: https://codepen.io/felipe_mare/pen/PWKZWQ

Comment: That is good solution +1 , yet I want to display curve instead of straight line, Have you any idea about it?  B'Coz it is continuously drawing line and I do not want that.

Comment: @coDemurDerer there might be a better way, but can store every point in an array and use the `beginShape()` function to display it